# Unable to fetch aws instance metadata -- ami-id.. command returns no output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scripting, metadata

I am trying to fetch ec2 metadata on aws using the curl command and I encounter this error. Can someone help me here.

```
sysadm@ip-172-31-44-113:~/three-questions/query-script$ cat script.sh 
#!bin/bash

TOKEN=`curl -X PUT "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token" -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 21600"` \
&& curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

curl -H "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: $TOKEN" -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id
```

---

```
sysadm@ip-172-31-44-113:~/three-questions/query-script$ sh script.sh 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    56  100    56    0     0   8032      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  9333
*   Trying 169.254.169.254:80...
* Connected to 169.254.169.254 (169.254.169.254) port 80 (#0)
> GET /latest/meta-data/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 169.254.169.254
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> X-aws-ec2-metadata-token: 
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 331
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Sun, 04 Dec 2022 07:23:08 GMT
< Last-Modified: Sun, 04 Dec 2022 06:12:40 GMT
< X-Aws-Ec2-Metadata-Token-Ttl-Seconds: 21600
< Connection: close
< Server: EC2ws
< 
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
block-device-mapping/
events/
hostname
identity-credentials/
instance-action
instance-id
instance-life-cycle
instance-type
local-hostname
local-ipv4
mac
managed-ssh-keys/
metrics/
network/
placement/
profile
public-hostname
public-ipv4
reservation-id
security-groups
services/
system
* Closing connection 0
tags/*   Trying 169.254.169.254:80...
* Connected to 169.254.169.254 (169.254.169.254) port 80 (#0)
> GET /latest/meta-data/ami-id HTTP/1.1
> Host: 169.254.169.254
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> X-aws-ec2-metadata-token:
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 21
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Sun, 04 Dec 2022 07:23:08 GMT
< Last-Modified: Sun, 04 Dec 2022 06:12:39 GMT
< X-Aws-Ec2-Metadata-Token-Ttl-Seconds: 21600
< Connection: close
< Server: EC2ws
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

Tried

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options \
    --instance-id i-023xxxxxxxxxxxxeef \
    --http-tokens required \
    --http-endpoint enabled \
    --http-put-response-hop-limit 3 \
    --instance-metadata-tags enabled
```

Comment: It's there and I am sure you have missed it. Check carefully end of this output, on the same line of your prompt.

Comment: I think that the `TOKEN` variable only exists for that one line. Try putting the last command at the end of the line, with `&&`, so it's doing `TOKEN=... && curl ... && curl ...`